# Pass values from fitnesse test data table to dbfit query

Tags: fixtures, fitnesse, dbfit

I want to get sql query which is to be passed in dbfit dynamically. I used columnfixture for this. I can set the query from my java fixture as variable in my fit test table but when I tried passing the same variable to dbfit it just consider that as a string than a variable. Below is my code.

```
!path lib/*.jar
!|dbfit.MySqlTest|

|set option|bind symbols|true|



!|fixture.GetSQLPojo|
|url|=getSQLQuery()|
|giturl| query | <--- this gives the value returned from custom fixture


!|Connect|jdbc connection|

!|Query|<<query| <--- here when i tried using the variable it wasn't working
|a|b|c|d|
|14|x|null|y|
```

so can anyone tell me how to pass variable from test data table to dbfit. I am a newbie to fitnesse and db fit pardon me if it a silly question or something. Was breaking my head for almost one day with this. Thanks in advance.

Update----

I have used symbolutil.setsymbols to save my SQL and when I can get the SQL by doing like this <

Answer (score 0):

The symbol should be prefixed with `:` not `<<`

```
!|Query|:query|
```

Comment: I tried with this and I finally got my query in this table... But it is getting prepended and appended with two single quotes  ' 'select * from table' '

Comment: OK - may be a limitation of DBFit that you can't include an entire SQL statement from a symbol.

Comment: This problem occurs only when I give  set option|bind symbols|true|  this is the case for all strings not only SQL. For eg if I give xyz to the symbol it is changed to 'xyz' with quotes added to the actual string